# Browser Back Button doesn't destroy the session in PassportJS + ExpressJS. How to kill/terminate the session entirely?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

The code for my Logout Mechanism is

```
app.get('/logout', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/');
    });
```

Am using a Express-session package using a secret key, haven't set Cookies anywhere.

While I click the browser Back button after logout, It still allows the user to go back to the page being authenticated. How do I terminate this session entirely?

isLoggedIn is just authenticating via PassportJS's isAuthenticated method. What is the way out here?

Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Edit: This is the session Id

[image]

Comment: It's most likely displaying content from the browser's cache, meaning it's not hitting the network, so there's not much you can do about that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set the `Cache-control` headers to `no-cache` *conditionally* for logged out users

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.user)
        res.header('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
    next();
});
```

This will force the browser to obtain new copy of the page even when they hit "back".

---

Note: This comes at the cost of disabling cache for ***all*** users that aren't logged in, which for the sake of this answer includes the ones that just logged out. You should probably find a way to distinguish between the two if you don't want to disable cache entirely for **all** logged out users. Something with sessions..

If you're sure that when user hits back, `'/login'` is the route that they will land on, then you can define it only there, thus saving yourself from the trouble of doing the above.

---

> Where exactly does this code go?
>
> ```
> app.get('/logout', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
>     req.logOut();
>     if (!req.user) 
>         res.header('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
>     res.redirect('/login');
> });
> ```
>
> Can it be used like this?

No.

`app.get` (or `app.use`) defines your routes. Documentation: http://expressjs.com/api.html#request

`app.get('/logout'...` will *only* be executed if the route `'/logout'` is requested by the client.

`app.use(...)` (without specifying any route) will be executed for all requests.

These route "middlewares" (as they are called) are also executed in succession to one another. (you'll learn more in the docs mentioned above)

You want to set the headers **before any other route**, so that whatever those other routes render, is rendered with the header that forcibly invalidated the user's cache.

```
// > HERE <
// before all the other routes

app.get('/logout'...
app.get('/login'...
app.get('/'...
app.get('/stuff'...
```

Comment: Thanks.. This might be a n00b question, but where exactly does this code go?
`code
    app.get('/logout', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
     req.logOut();
     if (!req.user)
     res.header('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
     res.redirect('/login');
    }); `

Can it be used like this?

Comment: @laggingreflex  What is user in `user` in `if (!req.user) ` ??  Is it something we define or is a something from `req`.

Comment: @laggingreflex Ohh okay.. Thanks.